# Adding word boundary to python regex capture group

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to preprocess text before parsing them to StanfordCoreNLP server. Some of my text looks like this.

" Conversion of code written in C# to Visual Basic .NET (VB.NET)."

The ".NET" confuses the server because it appears as a period and makes the single sentence into two. I wanted to replace '.' that appears in front of a word with 'DOT' so that sentence remains the same. Note that I don't want to change anything in 'VB.NET' because the StanfordCoreNLP recognizes that as one word (Proper noun).

This is what I tried so far.

```
print(re.sub(r"\.(\S+)", r"DOT\g<0>", text))
```

The result looks like this.

```
Conversion of code written in C# to Visual Basic DOT.NET (VBDOT.NET).
```

I tried adding word boundaries to the pattern `r"\b\.(\S+)\b"`. It didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r"\B\.\b", "DOT", text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p9iYBl/1).

The `\B\.\b` regex matches a dot that is either at the start of string or immediately preceded with a non-word char, and that is followed with a word char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QYBjrg):

```py
import re
text = "Conversion of code written in C# to Visual Basic .NET (VB.NET)."
print( re.sub(r"\B\.\b", "DOT", text) )
# => Conversion of code written in C# to Visual Basic DOTNET (VB.NET).
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `\b\.\b` doesn't work.

Comment: @akalanka `\b\.\b` matches a `.` that is located in between two word chars, e.g. `b.c`, `1.a`, `_._`.